# FacebookSdk Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, facebook, share

Recently I wanted to add Facebook share button in my app with the Facebook api, but I get this error when trying to install the app on my device:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uz.zgora.tourdebar/com.uz.zgora.tourdebar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.uz.zgora.tourdebar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:95)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6857)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
```

This is my `onCreate` method:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

    buttonShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_share);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    buttonShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().setQuote("This is useful link").setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://google.de")).build();
            if(ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)){
                shareDialog.show(linkContent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and this my layout (activity_main_drawer.xml):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_map"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_google_map"
        android:title="Map" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_list"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_bar_list"
        android:title="List" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

I think that there is a problem with this drawer. Maybe when I'm creating the button there is problem with `findviewbyid`, but I think I've tried everything and nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

From your `activity_main_drawer.xml`, you are using menu items. Are you sure you have the overriden `onCreateOptionsMenu()` function in your class file? Because you need to inflate the menu.

From [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource), you can see the required way for this.

Comment: now I moved 
        `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

        buttonShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nav_share);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);`
to my "onCreateOptionsMenu" and:

Comment: `if (id==R.id.nav_share){
            buttonShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().setQuote("This is useful link").setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://google.de")).build();
                    if(ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)){
                        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }`
to "onNavigationItemSelected".

Comment: It's not crushing the app when starting, but later when i swipe for drawer menu, and select share button, still it cushes with this error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`